# Override max width of specific docs (not all docs)

Tags: docusaurus

I have a specific "doc" in the "docs" section, for which I need the max width to be bigger (because it contains 2 IFrames side by side).

I see that the guy specifying the max-width is: `DocPageLayouMain`:

[image]

But this component doesn't receive as param a specific page. It is the same for all pages. A child of it, `DocItem` knows the current page (which may communicate via metadata that it needs the bigger size.

[image]

However, it doesn't have the "power" to make the width bigger.

Any hints of how I could achieve this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

I achieved my goal w/ the following modifs. However, I don't like that I've swizzeled a component = `DocItem/Layout` marked as "unsafe".

Run `docusaurus swizzle <insert theme> DocItem/Layout -- --wrap` to swizzle wrap.

```js
import React from 'react';
import Layout from '@theme-original/DocItem/Layout';
import {useDoc} from '@docusaurus/theme-common/internal';

export default function LayoutWrapper(props) {
  const doc = useDoc();
  return (
    <div class={doc.frontMatter.full_width ? "" : "container"}>
      <Layout {...props} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

`custom.css`:

```css
main > .container {
  /* 
    We disable this on the "normal" container, i.e. DocPage/Layout/Main.
    We want ONLY for this, hence we base our selector on the parent, which is a DOM element: <main>.
    We want to reuse this class in DocItem/Layout.
   */
  max-width: initial !important;
}
```

`my-page-that-wants-full-width.mdx`

```
---
description: Live demo
hide_table_of_contents: true
sidebar_position: 10
full_width: true
---

# Demo

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply set a custom CSS rule to the specific document by using it's generated `docs-doc-id`. As of Docusaurus v3.1.1, every document gets a unique ID as an HTML class.

Inspect the page with DevTools and the root `<html>` tag will have a class named like this: 
`docs-doc-id-path/from/docs/folder/to/specific/markdown/file`

For example, the document generated from `/docs/getting-started/intro.md` Markdown file, will have the `docs-doc-id-getting-started/intro` class.

To customize the parts of that document which was generated from Markdown, use the following in the `src/css/custom.css` file:

```css
/* Adding custom style to specific documents */
.docs-doc-id-getting-started\/intro .markdown {
  color: blue;
}
```

In your case, to increase the `max-width`, do the following:

```css
/* Adding custom style to specific documents */
.docs-doc-id-getting-started\/intro .markdown {
  max-width: 80%; /* or use pixel value: max-width: 800px */

  /* Another useful attribute to control the content width: */
  width: fit-content;
}
```

NOTE: I tested this with the `@docusaurus/preset-classic`, I don't know if using other presets change this behaviour.

---

Based on [this issue thread on docusaurus' GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/issues/4280#issuecomment-798949490).